# React Native: Can't sign Ad-hoc iOS OneSignal extension in AppCenter

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal, visual-studio-app-center, react-native-onesignal

I'm developing an app with React Native 0.64 that I build through Microsoft AppCenter. I'm using the react-native-one-signal sdk for the push notifications but I'm facing some issues when I'm trying to sign my OneSignalExtension with the "Provisioning profile" (no problems for the production build in the AppStore).

Here is my error:

> error: "OneSignalServiceExtension" requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'OneSignalServiceExtension' from project 'xxxxx')

I've checked my extension provisioning profile and there is the "AppCenter" feature enabled.

[image]

And here is my xCode settings for the OneSignalExtension.

[image]

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? Is there a step I'm missing or anything else ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue..